# Preventing high memory usage when using Sockets with NIO

Tags: java, file, sockets, nio

I'm developing client - server architecture for files exchanging, it's for my own purpose. Everything works great except memory usage. After I've sent some files I realized my applications memory management isn't so effective when I was trying to send some videos(something about 900MB), my client's and server's memory usage was about 1,5GB.

I used NetBeans's Profiler and it said that the problem is byte array.

```
//Client side

FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
FileChannel ch = f.getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192*32);
int nRead = 0;
while ((nRead = ch.read(bb)) != -1) {
    if (nRead == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    bb.position(0);
    bb.limit(nRead);
    send.writeObject(Arrays.copyOfRange(bb.array(), 0, nRead));
    send.flush();
    bb.clear();   
}
f.close();
ch.close();
bb.clear();
send.writeObject(0xBB);
send.flush();




//Server side

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
FileChannel fco = fos.getChannel();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192 * 32);
do {

Object received = download.readObject();
if (received instanceof byte[]) {
    byte[] bytes = (byte[]) received;
    buffer.put(bytes);
    buffer.flip();
    buffer.position(0);
    buffer.limit(bytes.length);
    fco.write(buffer);
    buffer.clear();
} else if (received instanceof Integer) {
    Integer tempx = (Integer) received;
    state = (byte) (tempx & (0xFF));
}
} while (received != (byte) 0xBB);
fco.close();
fos.close();
```

Is there anyway to fix it, I mean is it possible to clean used memory? Limiting bytebuffer doesnt work properly so I've limited the byte array from buffer, I didn't attached whole code, because working with files is the problem.

SCREEN FROM PROFILER - CLIENT'S MEMORY USAGE
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouTDk.png

Comment: Why are you calling `send.flush`?! And are you measuring usage of physical memory or virtual memory?

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot about this, send is ObjectOutputStream, and download is ObjectInputStream.

Comment: I was measuring physical memory in Windows Task Menager.

Comment: Why are you creating a ByteBuffer to fill it with bytes and then write it out again? Can't you write out the byte[] directly?

Comment: Also worth checking the `isDirect()` method on your `ByteBuffer`. Direct buffers frequently have weird memory management strategies and may exist outside the garbage collection heap.

Comment: @TimB methods from FileChannel for filling buffer return ByteBuffer, I've already tested it with FileStream and byte array the problem still occurs.

Comment: Are you sure it is actually a problem? Does it keep growing indefinitely or does it stabilise? Does a full GC run make any difference?

Comment: Running GC isn't changed anything. When I was sending photos memory usage stabilised to 150MB.

Comment: @JesanFafon How often should I use isDirect?

Comment: Just once. It should just be the getter for the `direct` boolean property on your buffer.

Answer (score 3):

- Your buffers are 8192 times 32. If you have memory problems, make them smaller. You don't need them that big for network purposes. It's also a strange way to write 256k.
- Don't create pointless copies of byte arrays. ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared() will do what you need there.
- I would strongly suggest getting rid of the serialization and just copying the bytes. The code becomes much simpler and you have less copies of the data, especially at the receiving end.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct solution - but you should use try-with-resources blocks on all your streams. That will prevent any possible resource leaks that may be making your situation worse.

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
   // Do stuff here, fos is automatically closed when you leave the block
}
```